# kNN search using distance fitted to a training set of similar pairs

Tags: machine-learning, distance, k-nearest-neighbour

I want to perform k-nearest neighbor search in multidimensional space but not using for example L2 distance but I want user to specify some "similar" pairs-examples and then perform search using this information.

What algorithm I can use for this?

Comment: Please, do NOT [cross-post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/knnsearch-using-examples).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you look at metric learning, and then perform k-nn with the learned metric. Here's a [Matlab toolkit](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~liuy/distlearn.htm) for it, or a [useful talk](http://cui.unige.ch/AI-group/teaching/dmc/09-10/cours/dm16-ml.pdf). If you're providing similar pairs with their distances, then you can learn the metric directly: if not, you can learn it by making an assumption like: the distance between similar pairs is less than the distance between the members of the pairs and other non-similar instances.

Answer (score 1):

My advisor and I wrote an algorithm called *k*-information gain nearest neighbors, which I think will be helpful for you. One of the basic differences between our approach and that of typical knn is that we use [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) as the distance metric--that is, after training, the class of a new document is determined by the *k* most similar documents, in the information theoretic sense.

Here's the paper describing for text classification: [Ambert & Cohen, 2011](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2077967), but people have used it for other applications as well.